# How do I create a countdown timer using real time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown, countdowntimer

I have developed the below code, which creates a div pop up box for 1 minute and disappears for 9 minutes. The div pop up box appears every 10 minutes on the hour based on the time on your device and it continuous.

```js
function showPopup() {
  var now = new Date();
  if ((now.getMinutes() % 10) == 0) {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    }, 60 * 1000); // Display for 1 minute
  } else {
    document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
    setTimeout(showPopup, 30 * 1000); // Rteyr every 30 seconds
  }
}
showPopup();
```

```css
.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="popup" class="inner">
    This is the pop-up.
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looking to create a piece of text to show the time in minutes the length to wait, when the div pop up box is not appearing, until the div pop up box appears, so:

“9 minutes to wait”
“8 minutes to wait”
“7 minutes to wait”
“6 minutes to wait”
“5 minutes to wait”
“4 minutes to wait”
“3 minutes to wait“
“2 minutes to wait”
“1 minute to wait”

With only the minutes counting down and with the “1 minute” without an “s” at the end. Would this be possible using the same code?

Comment: No, you will need some changes, nothing big, though.

Comment: Okay, thank you, would you know what changes I would need to do?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1yfv4u2/). The fiddle currently  shows seconds, but it should be trivial to change it to minutes.

Comment: Oh brilliant, nice one, thank you! It was taking me ages to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to update a comment in the code, [here's the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1yfv4u2/1/).

Comment: Sorry, I wonder if the order could be changed, so the pop up doesn’t show straight away but after the 9 minutes when the page is loaded? Sorry, but honestly thank you.

Comment: [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/tyohjbzg/2/)? If you don't want show the text before the first pop-up, just call the function with a timeout of 9 minutes.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry do you have a link of the new example. Sorry and thank you again

Comment: Hmm ... I've messed something up with the links, https://jsfiddle.net/g2k7sjeh/ , and again ... now the link is correct.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much. Sorry I have been lookign over it for so long my brain was cooked. Honestly thank you, life saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. Feel free to ask if in case of having any doubt :)

```
function showPopup() {
var now = new Date();
if ((now.getMinutes() % 10) == 0) {
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML =  'This is the pop-up.'
   setTimeout(function() {
     //document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = '9 Minutes to wait.'
   }, 60 * 1000); // Display for 1 minute
} else {
   var x = 10 - now.getMinutes()%10
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
   if (x == 1){
      document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = x + ' '+ 'Minute to wait.'
   }
   else{
      document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = x + ' '+ 'Minutes to wait.'
   } 
    setTimeout(showPopup, 30 * 1000); // Rteyr every 30 seconds
    }}
   showPopup();
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I will have a look. Thank you